# Special PCIe x8 in regular PCIe x16 slot?

Tags: pci-express

[image: HP NC375i NIC]

Is it safe to plug it into a regular PCIe x16 slot on a desktop motherboard? The pic is HP NC375i NIC.

Answer (score 3):

Yes. A larger PCI express slot fits all smaller PCI express cards. That means you can plug an x1, x2, x4 or x8 card into an x16 slot, x4 card into x8 slot, and so on.

The reverse is also true. You can plug a larger card into a smaller slot, for example x16 card into x8 slot, provided that the rear side of the slot is open. Of course now the card can only operate at the slower speed

---

## Edit:

It turns out many people have actually asked this: [HP nc375i Quad-Ethernet adapter, will it work in standard PCI-Express port (non-HP?)](https://www.reddit.com/r/servers/comments/712nvx/hp_nc375i_quadethernet_adapter_will_it_work_in/dn81bzd/), and there are people who tried to [plug the card into an x16 slot](https://www.reddit.com/r/homelab/comments/5ipgg2/did_i_break_my_nic/) and realized that the proprietary connector doesn't fit

[image: HP NC375i in x16 slot]

The OP then cut the whole non-pin part away which results in the failure of the card

[image: HP NC375i cut]

That's because the cut-out part contains metal and possibly some electronic components. I think if we grind the non-pin part (or simply cut the back of the x16 slot) to make it fit the x16 slot and cover the non-x8 part so the pins don't touch the x16 pins then it might work

[image: HP NC375i backside]

The marked part above is the proprietary non-x8 part

However a simpler and non-destructive solution would be using an x8 [riser card](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riser_card)

[image: x8 riser card]

Comment: If you look at the picture this is not a standard x8 card.

Comment: I don't have the ability to check those pins remotely without any direct comparison. If you have the card with you why don't just check it with a mainboard? If the card fit, it would work, otherwise you can't plug it in

Comment: The rear part of the pins are HP proprietary (HP Proliant system board). I am not sure it it is safe to plug that into a PCIe x16 slot, possibly killing the motherboard...